# Kion signifas "through" en ĉi tiu kunteksto?

Tags: translation

Biden-Harris Administration Extends Space Station Operations Through 2030
https://blogs.nasa.gov/spacestation/2021/

En ĉi tiu kunteksto, ĉu "through" signifas "ĝis 2030, sed ne plu" aŭ "ĝis 2030 kaj plu"?

Answer (score 1):

Lasu min analizi la anglan frazon.

1. **Biden-Harris Administration**

Kvankam la usona maniero ŝajnas esti, ke oni nomas periodojn kiel ili estus registaj eraoj, mi preferas pli kompreneblan manieron "prezidento Biden" aŭ "prezidento Biden kun sia vicprezidento Harris".

2. **extends**

La artikolo parolas pri "commitment", sed mi ne certas, ĉu temas pri "dekreto", "aserto" aŭ nur "volo". Eble temas pri forta volo, do mi elektas la verbon "aserti".

3. **operations**

Laŭ PIV estas du vortoj

- [operacio](https://vortaro.net/#operacio_kd), kiu temas pri kirurgiaj procedoj, ekonomiaj rimedoj aŭ matematiko
- [operaco](https://vortaro.net/#operaco_kd), kiu temas pri militaj agoj

Al mi "operaco" estas tro milita termino ĉi-okaze, ĉar la angla frazo signifas nur, ke oni daŭre uzu la stacion aŭ la stacio funkciu.

4. **Through 2030**

Miakomprene la angla esprimo "through 2030" signifas, ke la funkciado daŭras de la nuna momento ĝis la fino de la jaro 2030. Ankaŭ la prepozicio "[ĝis](https://vortaro.net/#%C4%9Dis_kd)" estas inkluziva, t.e. "ĝis (la jaro) 2030" egalas al "la jaroj antaŭ la jaro 2030 kaj tiu jaro"

#### Sume

"Prezidento Biden asertas, ke la funkciado de la Internacia Spacostacio daŭras ĝis la jaro 2030."

aŭ

"Prezidento Biden asertas, ke la Internacia Spacostacio daŭras funkcii ĝis la jaro 2030."

Comment: Dankon pro la klarigo.

Answer (score 1):

> La administracio de Biden-Harris plilongigas kosmostaciajn laborojn/operaciojn ĝis 2030

- **administration** = administrantaro/administracio; la tuta ekipo.
- **extends** = plilongigas; opone al ĉesado, kiel antaŭe estis minacate.
- **operations** = laborojn/taskojn; bedaŭrinde *operacio* havas tro limigantan difinon.
  Mi emus tamen uzi la terminon *operacio*. *Mastrumado* same eblus. *Tasko* estus tro specifa. *Funkciado* estus trafa, tamen tro pasiva.
- **through** = ĝis / kontinue ĝis la fino [continuing in time towards completion of (a process or period)]. Kongrue al *extends*.

Answer (score 0):

Ĝi signifas "ĝis 2030, sed ne plu", sed oni uzis ĉi tiun esprimmanieron, kiu ne ŝajnas tre klara, ĉar poste oni eble denove plilongigos la tempon preter 2030.